# Xcode entitlement - how?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to push a new version of my app to the App Store but repeatedly get (see below error) in return.

It says I had not set my entitlement in the app. So I checked my old build Xcode environment and did not see anything about entitlements there. On `developer.apple.com` portal my app is check marked with the Push Notification entitlement.

However, to move on I tried adding the push entitlement on the new build machine

1. Confusion - there is no "Push Notification" entitlement in the Xcode select menu, only "Notification Content Extension" and "Notification Service Extension". I now used the "Content Exetension"
2. Confusion. Adding this extension it asked me to add a new product name which in turn appended a new string to my valid bundle id:

`my.bundle.id.NewProduct`

Accepting this I now see a `E` in a circle under my proper app build target. Will this be included automatically in the build? I do not understand why it did not happen on my previous build machine since I do not have that circled E etc there. It just might have happened due to update history of Xcode.

What am I doing : I'm trying to enable Firebase Cloud Messaging with my app. Previously I only had APNS.

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

Comment: You don't want to add a notification extension target.  Delete that.  Go into your existing target in Xcode, go to "Signing & capabilities", click "+ capability" & select push notifications

Comment: But that menu has no "push notifications extension" as I mentioned above. Only Notification Content Extension and Notification Service Extension...?

Comment: Ah hell, NM. There are two plusses and I kept pushing the new target instead of the other. Cheers!